# How to use trim function in codeigniter active record

Tags: codeigniter

I wrote the below in format of codeigniter

```
$this->db->select("TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM column_name )");
$this->db->get(table_name)->result_array();
```

But when I printed the query using `$this->db->last_query()`, I found a space after comma(,) like this
`SELECT TRIM(BOTH ', ' FROM column_name ) FROM table_name.` How to remove that space so that my query will run.

Comment: use this->db->query("SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM column_name) FROM table_name");

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to write it in active record format inside $this->db->select()

Answer (score 1):

You can set in the validation message like :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('input_field', 'Input Field', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
```